# What's up with the unanswered list?

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions

There seems to be something strange going on with the [highly voted unanswered list](https://math.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes). The first couple of hits seem fine, although I have a vague recollection that there were more very highly voted questions with no answers recently.

From the eighth or ninth question or so, it's obvious that something has happened. There are definitely many more unanswered questions with vote score of more than 8, which the tenth question in the list has.

The number of questions on the right-hand side seems to correspond to the number of questions listed. I get 1351 pages when viewing 50 questions, which suggests the number of question should be around 67550 which agrees well with the stated number.

But where's the rest?

EDIT: This was apparently a temporary issue and it now seems to be fixed.

Comment: I searched the main meta for any discussion about this, but I couldn't find any. Also, although I can't be sure, [the same list on meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/unanswered) appears not to have the same problem, which would suggest that this is not a network-wide issue.

Comment: I've seen similar bugs in the past on SE sites, they were caused by some problem in the way SE caches those lists.